# How to populate a form with previously created form saved in the local storage and edit it in React

Tags: reactjs

I created a method "editPerson()" to edit a previously created form. when i populate the elements of the form in the react form, it seems that react states do not change. I need to know the best way to populate my Form to make the client able to edit it and update it to the local Storage.

This is the editPerson() method.

```
import React from 'react';
import Form from './Form'
import './styles.css';

let persons;

let localStoragePersons = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personsForms"));
persons = localStoragePersons !== null ? localStoragePersons : [];

class Table extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <div className="TableDiv">
                <Form showData={this.showData} persons={this.persons}  />
                <table className="myTable" id="editableTable" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Firstname</th>
                            <th>Lastname</th>
                            <th>Date Of Birthday</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                            <th>Favorite Choclates</th>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <th>Type of Work</th>
                            <th>Hobbies</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Favorite Color</th>
                        </tr>

                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );

    }



    editPerson(ID) {
        document.getElementsByName('submit!')[0].value = 'Update';
        let target;
        let i;
        for (i = 0; i < persons.length; ++i) {
            if (persons[i].ID === ID) {
                target = persons[i].firstName; break;
            }
        }


        for (i = 0; i < persons.length; ++i) {

            if (persons[i].firstName === target) {
                document.getElementsByName('firstName1')[0].value = persons[i].firstName;
                document.getElementsByName('lastName1')[0].value = persons[i].lastName;
                document.getElementsByName('bday1')[0].value = persons[i].birthday;
                document.getElementsByName('salary')[0].value = persons[i].salary;
                document.getElementsByName('Choclates').values = persons[i].Choclates;
                document.getElementsByName('Gender')[0].value = persons[i].Gender;
                document.getElementsByName('description')[0].value = persons[i].Description;
                let choc = persons[i].Choclates;
                let k;
                let j = 0;
                for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                    if (document.getElementsByName('Choclates')[k].value === choc[j]) {
                        document.getElementsByName('Choclates')[k].selected = true;
                        j++;
                    } else {
                        document.getElementsByName('Choclates')[k].selected = false;
                    }
                }
                let favC = persons[i].favoriteColor;
                document.getElementById('colorselectionbox1').value = favC;
                this.changeboxCOLOR();
                if (
                    document.getElementsByName('workType')[0].value === persons[i].workType) {
                    document.getElementsByName('workType')[0].checked = true;
                } else {
                    document.getElementsByName('workType')[1].checked = true;
                }
                let hobbies = persons[i].Hobbies;
                let p = 0;
                let f;
                for (f = 0; f < 5; f++) {

                    if (document.getElementsByName('hobby')[f].value === hobbies[p]) {
                        document.getElementsByName('hobby')[f].checked = true;
                        p++;
                    } else {
                        document.getElementsByName('hobby')[f].checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }


    changeboxCOLOR() {
        let boxcolor1 = document.getElementsByName('colorselectionbox');
        let selectedboxcolor = null;
        for (let i = 0; i < boxcolor1.length; i++) {
            if (boxcolor1[i].selected) {
                selectedboxcolor = boxcolor1[i].value;
                break;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("colorselectionbox1").style.backgroundColor = selectedboxcolor;
    }

}


export default Table;
```

and this is the child component

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles.css'

let persons = [];
if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personsForms")) !== null)
    persons = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personsForms"));
let Counter = persons.length;
let editID;
class Form extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            ID: -1,
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            Gender: 'Male',
            birthday: '',
            salary: 0,
            Choclates: [],
            workType: '',
            Hobbies: [],
            favHobbies: {
                'Reading': false, 'Swimming': false, 'Listen to music': false, 'Work out': false, 'Sing': false
            },
            Description: '',
            favoriteColor: 'red',
            eventName: 'newFormEvent'
        }

    }



    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>First Name: </label>
                    <input value={this.state.firstName}
                        name="firstName1"
                        placeholder='First Name'
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ firstName: e.target.value })}
                    /><span className="Errors" id="firstName" name="firstName"></span>
                    <br></br><br></br>


                    <label>Last Name: </label>
                    <input value={this.state.lastName}
                        name="lastName1"
                        placeholder='Last Name'
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ lastName: e.target.value })}
                    /><span className="Errors" id="lastName" name="lastName"></span>
                    <br></br><br></br>


                    <label>Gender: </label>
                    <select name="Gender" onChange={e => {
                        let options = e.target.options;
                        let selectedGender = null;
                        let i = 0;
                        for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                            if (options[i].selected)
                                selectedGender = options[i].value;
                        }
                        this.setState({ Gender: selectedGender });
                    }} >
                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                    </select> <br></br><br></br>


                    <label>Birthday: </label>
                    <input type="date" name="bday1" value={this.state.birthday}
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ birthday: e.target.value })}
                    /> <span className="Errors" id="birthday" ></span><br></br><br></br>


                    <label>Salary: </label> <input type="number" name="salary"
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ salary: e.target.value })}
                        min="1" step="0.01" placeholder="0.00"
                    /><span className="Errors" id="salary"></span> <br></br><br></br>


                    <label>What do you prefer?: </label><span className="Errors" id="Choclates" ></span> <br></br>
                    <select name="SelectChoclates" multiple onChange={e => {
                        let options = e.target.options;
                        let values = [];
                        let i = 0;
                        for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                            if (options[i].selected) {
                                values.push(options[i].value);
                            }
                        }
                        this.setState({ Choclates: values });
                    }}>
                        <option name="Choclates" value="Mars">Mars</option>
                        <option name="Choclates" value="Snickers">Snickers</option>
                        <option name="Choclates" value="Flake">Flake</option>
                        <option name="Choclates" value="Galaxy">Galaxy</option>
                        <option name="Choclates" value="Bounty">Bounty</option>
                    </select> <br></br><br></br>


                    <label onChange={e => {
                        this.setState({ workType: e.target.value });
                    }}>Type of work: <span className="Errors" id="workType"></span><br></br>
                        <input type="radio" name="workType" ref="pt" value="Part-Time"
                        />Part - Time < br ></br >
                        <input type="radio" name="workType" ref="ft" value="Full-Time"
                        />Full - Time < br ></br >
                    </label> <br></br>


                    <label>Select between 2 and 4 hobbies: </label><span className="Errors" id="Hobbies"></span> <br></br>
                    {this.renderFavHobbies()}

                    <br></br><br></br>

                    <label>Description: </label> <span className="Errors" id="Description"></span><br></br>
                    <textarea name="description" ref="textArea1" rows="4" cols="50" maxLength="150" onChange={e => this.setState({ Description: e.target.value })}></textarea> <br></br>
                    <input type="button" value="More Characters?" onClick={() => {
                        this.refs.textArea1.setAttribute('maxlength', '200');
                    }} /> <br></br><br></br>


                    <label>Select one color: </label> <br></br>
                    <select onChange={e => {
                        let val = e.target.value;
                        this.setState({ favoriteColor: val });
                        this.refs.coloredBox.style.backgroundColor = val;
                    }}>
                        <option name="colorselectionbox" value="red">Red</option>
                        <option name="colorselectionbox" value="blue">Blue</option>
                        <option name="colorselectionbox" value="green">Green</option>
                        <option name="colorselectionbox" value="purple">Purple</option>
                        <option name="colorselectionbox" value="black">Black</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>
                        <div className="coloredbox" id="colorselectionbox1" ref="coloredBox"   ></div>
                    </label><br></br><br></br>


                    <input type="submit" name="submit!" value="Create" />
                    <input type="reset" />
                    <br></br><br></br>
                </form >


            </div>
        );
    }

saveForm(myForm) {
        if (document.getElementsByName('submit!')[0].value === 'Create') {
            myForm.ID = null;
        } else {
            myForm.ID = editID;
        }
        if (myForm.ID !== -1)
            myForm.ID = Counter;
        Counter++;
        persons.push(myForm);
        localStorage.setItem("personsForms", JSON.stringify(persons));

        this.props.showData();
    }
```

Comment: Do not manipulate DOM in react, mate. Set your dat to state in your "EditPerson" method. Then set state will trigger a render. And in render you can get updated values in your input.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Can you please elaborate more, i am new to react and i don't know a better way to do so.

Comment: What it pops out is that you have to do some tutorial, maybe 1 day would be sufficient to get confident with React basis, before moving furher

Comment: do you recommend any tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not manipulating the DOM in react. You can just get your values from `localstorage` and drop it in your component state in the `componentDidMount()` by using `setState()`. then you can use `controlled components` to populate the form fields with the `value` prop.